# New iOS Token Based Authentication Notifications: how?

Tags: php, ios, authentication, token

I watched the video at: [The WWDC 2016 session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/724/) but I am sorry I was not able to make a sense of it to actually register to send notifications with the new system. I downloaded the APNsAuthKey certificate and got stuck there. The video talks about signing tokens with that but I am totally blank about what that means, when to be implemented in php. Is there some tutorial about how to send notifications with the new token based authentication? My old certificates elapse on March 16 and so I am quite in a hurry to implement the new system. May someone help?

Comment: I found a tutorial at:
http://gobiko.com/blog/token-based-authentication-http2-example-apns/
but unfortunately I got an error there reported when I try to execute it.